# java.security.AccessControlException: access denied can't be fixed in security/java.policy

Tags: java

I'm using SonarQube and embedding addon there
When I run SonarQube it gives an exception

> java.security.AccessControlException: access denied
> ("java.io.FilePermission"
> "/opt/sonarqube/data/web/deploy/plugins/JbcSonarPluginjdk11/META-INF/conf"
> "write")

I tried to solve it using

```
/etc/java-11-openjdk/security/java.policy
```

adding there smth like

```
grant {
    // SonarQube plugin allow
    permission java.io.FilePermission "/opt/sonarqube/data/web/deploy/plugins/JbcSonarPluginjdk8/-", "read,write";
};
```

but this did not help
I tried also

```
permission java.io.FilePermission "/opt/sonarqube/data/web/deploy/plugins/JbcSonarPluginjdk11/META-INF/conf", "read,write";
```

or

```
permission java.io.FilePermission "/opt/sonarqube/data/web/deploy/plugins/JbcSonarPluginjdk11/META-INF/*", "read,write";
```

That did not help

I even tried this

```
permission java.security.AllPermission;
```

but in this case ElasticSearch gives an error

> ERROR: [1] bootstrap checks failed. You must address the points
> described in the following [1] lines before starting Elasticsearch.
> bootstrap check failure [1] of [1]: granting the all permission
> effectively disables security ERROR: Elasticsearch did not exit
> normally - check the logs at /opt/sonarqube/logs/sonarqube.log

I wonder - how can I allow JDK to create a file there?

Comment: did you check the OS file permissions? Is Sonarqube running with a user that is allowed to write there?

Comment: Yes, it can writhe there:

`ls -l
total 27348
-rwxr-xr-x 1 sonarqube sonarqube 27998208 May  4 17:09 JbcSonarPlugin_jdk11.jar
-rwxr-xr-x 1 sonarqube sonarqube      737 Apr  1 09:12 README.txt

touch testfile.txt

ls -l
total 27348
-rwxr-xr-x 1 sonarqube sonarqube 27998208 May  4 17:09 JbcSonarPlugin_jdk11.jar
-rwxr-xr-x 1 sonarqube sonarqube      737 Apr  1 09:12 README.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sonarqube sonarqube        0 May 10 11:59 testfile.txt

pwd
/opt/sonarqube/extensions/plugins`

Comment: seems you tried the permissions in `/opt/sonarqube/extensions/plugins`, but the exception occurs in `/opt/sonarqube/data/web/deploy/plugins/` (so probably the folder where Tomcat or whatever container you use explodes the JAR file into)
Also I noticed that in your first trial with a policy you specified "...jdk8" instead of "...jdk11" - was this a typo for the post or also for the real try?

Comment: Let me clarify some details here. I have 2 version of the plugin: JbcSonarPlugin_jdk8.jar and JbcSonarPlugin_jdk11.jar. I tried any of these (only one can be used, otherwise I have an error). It needs to be put in /opt/sonarqube/extensions/plugins
Depending on the plugin version it creates either /opt/sonarqube/data/web/deploy/plugins/JbcSonarPluginjdk8 or /opt/sonarqube/data/web/deploy/plugins/JbcSonarPluginjdk11

with the following structure

6.5M    ./META-INF/lib/libMonitor
8.0K    ./META-INF/lib/target
29M     ./META-INF/lib
29M     ./META-INF
That's why I can use either 8 or 11

Comment: It's interesting, that plugin can create it's structure in */opt/sonarqube/data/web/deploy/plugins/JbcSonarPluginjdk11* (I mean META-INF dir and all recursive directories and files) but throws an exception for */opt/sonarqube/data/web/deploy/plugins/JbcSonarPluginjdk11/META-INF/conf*
with the same java.policy settings

I do believe that this is something wrong with the plugin and I need to talk to plugin's developers but first I want to see if I have any misconfiguration here

BTW I'm also able to create */opt/sonarqube/data/web/deploy/plugins/JbcSonarPluginjdk11/META-INF/conf* manually

Comment: Please put clarifications as updates into your question - not every user on SO will read all the long comments to get the most recent version ;) 
And probably the plugin itself does not create any folder but the "container" will do so by exploding the jar file (container in this case means Tomcat or Jetty or another web application server).
So with which user does that server run? (probably "sonarqube") Did you try to create a file in the correct folder as that user?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by just downgrading SonarQube from 9.4 to 8.9.8 **LTS** version of the application
Now all the stuff is created where it needs to be created even without modifying */etc/java-11-openjdk/security/java.policy*

```
pwd
/opt/sonarqube-8.9.8.54436/data/web/deploy/plugins/JbcSonarPluginjdk11/META-INF
ls -l
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 2 sonarqube sonarqube 4096 May 12 16:58 conf
drwxr-xr-x 4 sonarqube sonarqube 4096 May 12 16:58 lib
drwxr-xr-x 3 sonarqube sonarqube 4096 May 12 16:58 log
drwxr-xr-x 3 sonarqube sonarqube 4096 May 12 16:58 log_T24
-rw-r--r-- 1 sonarqube sonarqube    1 May 12 16:58 uid
-rw-r--r-- 1 sonarqube sonarqube    0 May 12 16:58 uid_lock
```